# How do Two Routers Port-Forwarding Work?

Tags: port-forwarding

My aim is to backup my Office PC (behind public IP) to Home PC (behind public IP) over the internet.

The solution I am currently considering is to use `rsync`.

My network configuration is given bellow.

[image]

I have read some blogs regarding making the computer using public IP accessible via the Internet. One of the solutions they have is to use port forwarding. There they mentioned forwarding the port on my home router. What about the ISP router? I do not have access to the ISP router. How port forwarding is supposed to work here?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, we don't know how your ISP configured it's router. There is no definitive answer that can be given. I would suggest you call your ISP and ask them what you are capable of doing with their router.

Another issue will be whether or not your work and home public IPs are static. Typically, home IPs are dynamic and can change over time. This can cause connection issues, if you aren't aware if the change.

Based on your level of networking, you might want to consider a cloud based backup or storage system. They are easy to configure and will allow you to move files easily from one system to others.

Comment: My home IP is static. Should I call my ISP and ask them to forward a port to my IP?